# Excel: Referencing a table to another table

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have a worksheet that looks something like this

```
Derrick  123456   good credit
warren   325234   bad credit
john     645345   bad credit
martin   123142   bad credit
Jiren    647546   good credit
```

I am looking for a formula to search column 3 and if it returns bad credit it draws the values to the left of it on a new sheet for all the bad credits. Conditional formatting is it called?

Sorry for being vague, excel is not my cup of tea.

Edit:
Filtering Worked best as the array formula slowed down the workbook significantly, thanks to pnut, don't know why he deleted his responses.

Comment: If you want to do this on a regular basis and you do not want to do it manually each time, then you will need vba.

Comment: I am going through the first list and want the bad credit one to be updated while I am going through @pnuts, how do I check if I have vba @Scott?

Comment: You have vba, you just need to write the code.  You have an array formula answer, but be aware that too many of those on a large data set will crash excel.  If you data set is small then go with that, if it is large (more than a few thousand lines) then vba will be needed and you will need to have code written, either by you or someone else.

Comment: pnuts, the name and the number that goes along, thanks scott.

Answer (score 0):

In sheet2 use the following:
For first column in A2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6="bad credit",ROW(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6),99999),ROW(A1))-1),"")
```

For the second column in B2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6="bad credit",ROW(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$6),99999),ROW(A1))-1),"")
```

Array formulas press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>
change the references A2:A6, B2:B6, C2:C6 to correspond to the last row in your Data (starting in 2nd row) 
 Keep the $ for fixed references
You can drag each formula in its column

Comment: Thank, just as the post pnuts linked, with a few adjustments I was able to get it to work